# Simple extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$ by rational numbers

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, extension-field

I'm afraid this question might be considered opinion-based, but I dare. It might be considered opinion-based because it starts from a probably biased observation: In textbooks examples and discussions of [simple extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension) $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ by adjunction of an irrational number $\alpha$ abound: $\sqrt{2}$,$\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\sqrt{-2},\dots$ But I rarely find thorough discussions of rational extensions like

$$\mathbb{Z}\Big[\frac{1}{2}\Big] = \Big\{a_0 + \frac{a_1}{2} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{2^n}  \ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_k \in \mathbb{Z}\Big\} = \Big\{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{2^k}  \ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_k \in \mathbb{Z}\Big\}$$

Is my impression deceptive, and extensions $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$ with $p \in \mathbb{N}$ are in fact  as important and interesing than extensions by irrational numbers? Or is it so, that they are not found so important and interesting? If so: For which reasons? If not so: In which contexts?

Why I find them interesting:

- Other than for square roots, the polyomial doesn't collapse:

$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{p}] = \{a_0 + a_1\sqrt{p} + \dots + a_n\sqrt{p}^n  \ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{a_0 + a_1\sqrt{p}  \ |\ a_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

- $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}] = \Big\{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{p^k}  \ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, a_k \in \mathbb{Z}\Big\} = \Big\{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{p^k}  \ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}, |a_k| < p\Big\}$
- Other than for square roots, each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ can be approximated arbitrary well in $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$.
- Nevertheless it's far from being $\mathbb{Q}$.
- But it's not so far from being $\mathbb{R} = \Big\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{p^k}  \ |\ |a_k| < p\Big\}$ with its strong resemblance to the p-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p = \Big\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k p^k  \ |\ |a_k| < p\Big\}$
- $\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}][\frac{1}{3}][\frac{1}{5}][\frac{1}{7}]\dots$ but you may not drop a single prime number

There will be more to say about $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$ so any reference to a concise paper or textbook chapter would be very welcome.

Comment: You may not have seen them as much because they will usually be called something else. These are localizations of the integers in the multiplicative set given as the power of some prime.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you suggest why the much more intuitive term "simple rational extension of $\mathbb{Z}$" is not mentioned at all e.g. in the Wikipedia article on the localization of a ring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring)?

Comment: First, what would the word "simple" mean precisely there? Second, what makes an extension "rational"?

Comment: Extension by **one** rational number $1/p$.

Comment: So would extension by $1/6$ be simple?

Comment: Yes, why not...?

Comment: Because that is the same as extending first by $2$ and then by $3$, so to me that would make it seem not simple.

Comment: OK then, let $p$ be prime (as suggested in my question).

Comment: Ok, so what is it that makes this extension simple (in the sense the word is usually used in algebra)? I am not saying these are bad names for this thing, but if it is to be an intuitive name, then the words used should have meanings close to their usual ones.

Comment: Would you say that $\mathbb{Z}[1/2] = \{ a + b/2\ |\ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ would be the correct way to simply extend $\mathbb{Z}$ by $1/2$ (not the way as I did)?

Comment: That would not be a ring, since it has no square of $1/2$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "why". I am not even saying that it would be wrong to call this "simple", but if you want to do so, you need to show that it is indeed simple in the sense usually used in algebra, or the term would seem strange.

Comment: @Tobias Are you not aware of the standard meaning of "simple extension"?  OP gave a link in the question.